# PHP Post not working with twitter api

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Im trying to use the following PHP to add a favorite to my account:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fav = $_REQUEST['fav'];
    $connection->post('favorites/create', array('id' => $fav));
    echo "<div style='padding-bottom: 5px; color: #0099FF;'>Fav Created Successfully.</div>";

    }
?>
```

With the following form:

```
<form id="fav" method='post' action='index.php'>
    <input type="text" style="width: 346px;" name="fav" id="fav" ></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Fav This!" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Its not creating a favorite, Can anyone spot anything wrong with it?

PS: I am using the OAuth API:

```
 $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you don't need to add an "id" parameter.

Looking at [Twitter's Documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/favorites/create/:id) the URL to create a favorite would be http://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/create/12345.xml where "12345" is the ID of the tweet.

Comment: He's doing that by `array('id' => $fav)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = $connection->post('favorites/create/'.$fav);
```

The ID is not a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Im trying to use the following PHP to add a favorite to my account:

```
$favorite = $connection->post('favorites/create/'.$id);
```

where `$id` is the status id but favorite don't return nothing

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it, it says the following.

> This method requires a GET.

Although Twitter API *documentation* says it requires a POST. So, try to do a `GET` request on it:

```
 $response = $connection->get('favorites/create', array('id' => $fav));
 // now print the response to see if any error pops up:
 print_r($response);
```

Comment: This is using Oauth, $connection is the tokens.

Comment: And what error do you get using `print_r($response)` when you use a POST ?